# Deletar as imagens enviadas pelo ckeditor

Tags: php, ckeditor

Estou usando o editor CKeditor. Quando eu coloco uma imagem no texto no banco fica armazenado da seguinte maneira:

```
<p><img alt="" src="http://intranet.supersoft.com.br/novo/ckeditor-integrated/uploads/images/imagem.jpg" style="height:420px; width:660px" /></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Muita gente ficou incomodada ao saber que o WhatsApp havia adicionado ....
```

Como pegar apenas o caminho da imagem para eu usar o `unlink` quando eu remover o post a imagem também seja removida da pasta?

Comment: Furlan, sua imagem sempre estará dentro de tags?

Comment: sim @gmsantos, o codigo na pergunta, ta assim na linha do banco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [`DOM`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.dom.php) para manipular seu HTML no PHP.

```
<?php

$string = '<p><img alt="" src="http://intranet.supersoft.com.br/novo/ckeditor-integrated/uploads/images/imagem.jpg" style="height:420px; width:660px" /></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Muita gente ficou incomodada ao saber que o WhatsApp havia adicionado ....';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$imagesTag = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($imagesTag as $img){
    echo $img->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Esse código irá criar um [`DOMElement`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domelement.php) para cada tag `<img>` do seu código, e escrever o conteúdo do atributo `src`.

A partir dai, basta aplicar sua lógica para fazer o `unlink` do arquivo.

Comment: cara, obrigado, vou estudar mais sobre DOM, obrigado!